# Opening shapefiles in R using rgdal always better than using maptools?

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, rgdal, r-maptools

I found two basic ways to open shapefiles in R - using `rgdal` and `maptools`:

```
# 1
require(maptools)
shape_maptools <- readShapeLines("file.shp")

# 2
require(rgdal)
shape_rgdal <- readOGR(".", "file")
```

The data structures seem exactly the same in both cases (class SpatialLinesDataFrame, package sp). However, while [`rgdal` reads the projection properly, `maptools` does not](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles) (you possibly have to assign the CRS manually):

```
> proj4string(shape_maptools)
[1] NA
> proj4string(shape_rgdal)
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"
```

So, why would I ever use `maptools` to open shape files? I may only make a mistake of assigning
the CRS manually!

#### May I conclude that both ways are equivalent, but using `rgdal` is always safer way to do open a  shapefile?

Answer (score 4):

The following comparison of `maptools`, `rgdal` and `PBSMapping` from the National Center for Ecological Analysis and Synthesis might interest you:

["Read and write ESRI Shapefiles with R"](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles)

Answer (score 1):

maptools::readShapeLines() get problem with file name containing spacial character eg. German Umlaut.

rgdal can deal with such case